# What is the difference between Radio type and check box type in the html code?

Tags: html

What is the difference between Radio type and check box type in the html code  ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button

Comment: Welcome on stack overflow @Tarun Did you try to google answer to this question? First try to google it, then if you don't find answer, ask question here. You will just got negative votes, i'm just sayin' :) Happy coding

Comment: Please search before posting. This is a basic question with tons of answers.

Comment: radio buttons: single select & checkbox: multi select

Comment: Yes i searched there is no answer on google

Comment: i am able to select one or more button from radio button So why we use checkbox if radio button provides us to select more the one optioni.                                                                                                                   
 Mail<input type="radio" name="t1" >                                     female<input type="radio" name="t2 >                   <input type="submit">

Answer (score 4):

A radio input provides a single-selection user choice. It is often depicted as a empty circle (unselected) and filled circle (selected).

A checkbox input provides a multi-selection user choice. It is often depicted as an empty square (unselected) and a checkmark within a square (selected).

Semantically, the only difference between the two HTML elements is the `type="radio"` attribute for radio options and `type="checkbox"` attribute for checkbox options. Related elements should have the same `name` attribute.

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Radio Selection</legend>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="1">Option 1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="2">Option 2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="3">Option 3</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Checkbox Selection</legend>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1">Option 1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2">Option 2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="3">Option 3</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Are you sure you can have the same name on checkboxes without having an „array name“? I thought a checkboxes value is null when unchecked otherwise the defined value

Comment: I believe the array name syntax, e.g. `name="checkbox[]"`, is a PHP thing so the posted data can be retrieved as an array. For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox#Handling_multiple_checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

Both are user input type which can be used in forms but from a group of Radio buttons, only one can be selected. On the other side, from a group of checkboxes, any number of checkboxes can be selected.

Examples of when to use them:

**CHECKBOX:**

1.Your Fav Sports:

[ ] Cricket

[ ] Football

[ ] Tennis

[ ] Badminton

Answer can be 1 or many options for above question.

**RADIO BUTTON:**

2 Your Gender:

O Male

O Female

O Other

For the above question, only one option can be valid and hence the user can be forced to pick only one.

Comment: But i am able to select one or more button from radio button So why we use checkbox if radio button provides us to select more the one optioni.                                                                                                                   
 Mail<input type="radio" name="t1" >                                     female<input type="radio" name="t2 >                   <input type="submit">

Answer (score 0):

I'll use an example based on MDN's radio button documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

They make a note of the important distinction:

> **Note**: Checkboxes are similar to radio buttons, but with an important
>   distinction: radio buttons are designed for selecting one value out of
>   a set, whereas checkboxes let you turn individual values on and off.
>   Where multiple controls exist, radio buttons allow one to be selected
>   out of them all, whereas checkboxes allow multiple values to be
>   selected.

Select a maintenance drone:

○ Huey

○ Dewey

○ Louie

The user is prompted to select a maintenance drone out of three options with radio buttons. They only get one drone, so the **radio button enforces that only one can be checked**. The **user gets one choice**: *Which maintenance drone do you want?* This choice is a **which of these** question.

Select your maintenance drone(s):

☐ Huey

☐ Dewey

☐ Louie

Lets recreate this example with checkboxes instead. The user can now select all of the drones or none of them because **checkboxes allow the user to check as many or as few boxes as they want**. The **user has multiple choices**: D*o you want the Huey maintenance drone? (Y/N)*; *Do you want the Dewey maintenance drone? (Y/N)*; *Do you want the Louie maintenance drone? (Y/N)*. This is a series of **Yes-or-No** questions.